# How to drag and dismiss View Controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I would I accomplish this?

On Facebook, when we tap a gallery of pictures, it shows what appears to be a Table View Controller. And when we scroll to the top or to the end of the table, the view starts to dismiss. But it only fully dismisses when we actually release the finger from the screen.

The new Apple Music App also has this feature. It shows on the screen with the controls and the album's photo (when we're playing a song). We can do a pan gesture there, along the Y axis, and the view moves with the finger. And the view doesn't dismiss until we actually release the finger from the screen.

How can I implement this behaviour? And what API's should I be looking into? Is there an example you could point me to?

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18968629/proper-way-to-implement-a-custom-uiviewcontroller-interactive-transition-using-u

Comment: Down vote without a comment is like hit and run. Would you hit and run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check out UIPresentationController. I haven't used them myself, but they may be what you are looking for.